# PHP OpenSSL AES-256-CBC different output

Tags: php, openssl, aes

I'm using this code to encrypt:

```
    $content='Hello World';
            
    $output = openssl_encrypt(
        $content,
        'AES-256-CBC',
        '2EE3732CA11BAD106A2429C142136345',
        OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
        $iv
    );
            
    echo bin2hex($output);
```

And my output is: `bc08212ff2960c50327e4f1585f401b9`

But when I use this website https://www.javainuse.com/aesgenerator, my output is:
`5415dc0f7cc496be97f2dc9b9d5b2b42`

[image]

I need this output `5415dc0f7cc496be97f2dc9b9d5b2b42` on my code output.
Because in java programming language I get this result.

```
        String text="Hello World";

        String secretKey="2EE3732CA11BAD106A2429C142136345";

        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec("0000000000000000".getBytes());
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        instance.init(1, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        String output= stringToHex(instance.doFinal(text.getBytes()));

        System.out.println(output); //Output: 5415dc0f7cc496be97f2dc9b9d5b2b42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function with ..,$iv = '0000000000000000').

Comment: Thanks. My wrong was on hex2bin for IV